# Is NodeJS is suitable for websites - (ie. Port Blocking)?

Tags: node.js

I have gone through many painful months with is issue and I am now ready to let this go to the bin of "what-a-great-lie-for-websites-nodejs-is"!!!

All NodeJS tutorials discuss how to create a website. When done, it works. For one person at a time though. All requests sent to the port will be blocked by the first come-first-serve situation. Why? Because most requests sent to the nodejs server will have to get parsed, data requested from the database, data calculated and parsed, response prepared and sent back to the ajax call. (this is a mere simple website example).

Same applies for authentication - a request is made, data is parsed, authentication takes place, session is created and sent back to the requester.

No matter how you sugar coat this - All requests are done this way. Yes you can employ async functionality which will shorten the time spent on some portions, yes you can try promises, yes you can employ clustering, yes you can employ forking/spawning, etc... The result is always the same at all times: port gets blocked.

I tried responding with a reference so that we can use sockets to pass the data back and matching it with the reference - that also blocked it.

The point of the matter is this: when you ask for help, everyone wants all sort of code examples, but never go to the task of helping with an actual answer that works. The whole wide world!!!!! Which leads me to the answer that nodeJS is not suitable for websites.

I read many requests regarding this and all have been met with: "you must code properly"..! Really? Is there no NodeJS skilled and experienced person who can lend an answer on this one????!!!!!

Most of the NodeJS coders come from the PHP side - All websites using PHP never have to utilise any workaround whatsoever in order to display a web page and it never blocks 2 people at the same time. Thanks to the web server.

So how come NodeJS community cannot come to some sort of an asnwer on this one other than: "code carefully"???!!!

They want examples - each example is met with: "well that is a blocking code, do it another way", or "code carefully"!!! Come one people!!!

Think of the following scenario: One User, One page with 4 lists of records. Theoretically all lists should be filled up with records independently. What is happening because of how data is requested, prepared and responded, each list in reality is waiting for the next one to finish. That is on one session alone.

What about 2 people, 2 sessions at the same time?

So my question is this: is NodeJS suitable for a website and if it is, can anyone show and prove this with a short code??? If you can't prove it, then the answer is: "NodeJS is not suitable for websites!"

Here is an example based on the simplest tutorial and it is still blocking:

```
var express = require('express'),
    fs      = require("fs");

var app = express();
app.get('/heavyload', function (req, res) {
    var file    = '/media/sudoworx/www/sudo-sails/test.zip';

    res.send('Heavy Load');
    res.end();

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,fileContent) {

    });

});


app.get('/lightload', function (req, res) {
    var file    = '/media/sudoworx/www/sudo-sails/test.zip';
    res.send('Light Load');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(1337, function () {
    console.log('Listening!')
});
```

Now, if you go to "/heavyload" it will immediately respond because that is the first thing sent to the browser, and then nodejs proceeds reading a heavy file (a large file). If you now go to the second call "/lightload" at the same time, you will see that it is waiting for the loading of the file to finish from the first call before it proceeds with the browser output. This is the simplest example of how nodejs simply fails in handling what otherwise would be simple in php and similar script languages.

Like mentioned before, I tried as many as 20 different ways to do this in my career of nodejs programmer. I totally love nodejs, but I cannot get past this obstacle... This is not a complaint - it is a call for help because I am at my end road with nodejs and I don't know what to do.

I thank you kindly.

Comment: You have to ask such opinion based questions in website like https://www.quora.com/ not here only Questions based on particular technology which can be answer by experties in that field is allowed this may result in -ve reputation

Comment: Wat!? they are many big sites running on Node.js

Comment: It's not really our job to prove anything to you, "or else". If you are not happy with Node, there are other options.

Comment: "What about 2 people, 2 sessions at the same time?"-what?

Answer (score 0):

> is NodeJS suitable for a website

Definitely yes.

> can anyone show and prove this with a short code

No.

> All websites using PHP never have to utilise any workaround whatsoever
>   in order to display a web page and it never blocks 2 people at the
>   same time.

Node.js doesn't require any workarounds as well, it simply works without blocking.

**To more broadly respond to your question/complaint:**

A single `node.js` machine can easily serve as a web-server for a website and handle multiple sessions (millions actually) without any need for workarounds.

If you're coming from a `PHP` web-server, maybe instead of trying to migrate an existing code to a new `Node` website, first play with online **simple** website example of [`Node.js` + `express`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html), if that works well, you can start adding code that require long-running processes like reading from DBs or reading/writing to files and verify that visitors aren't being blocked (they shouldn't be blocked).

See [this tutorial](https://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/) on how to get started.

**UPDATE FOR EXAMPLE CODE**

To fix the supplied example code, you should convert your `fs.readFile` call to `fs.createReadStream`. `readFile` is less recommended for large files, I don't think `readFile` literally blocked anything, but the need to allocate and move large amounts of bytes may choke the server, `createReadStream` uses chunks instead which is much easier on the CPU and RAM:

```
    rstream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    var length = 0;
    rstream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        length += chunk.length;
        // Do something with the chunk
    });
    rstream.on('end', function () {  // done
        console.log('file read! length = ' + length);
    });
```

After switching your code to `createReadStream` I'm able to serve continues calls to `heavyload` / `lightload` in ~3ms each

**THE BETTER ANSWER I SHOULD HAVE WRITTEN**

`Node.js` is a single process architecture, but it has multi-process capabilities, using the [cluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster) module, it allows you to write master/workers code that distributes the load across multiple workers on multiple processes.

You can also use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) to do the clustering for you, it has a built-in load balancer to distribute to work, and also allows for scaling up/down without downtime, see [this](https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/).

In your case, while one process is reading/writing a large file, other processes can accept incoming requests and handle them.

Comment: Hi I updated my question with a code example based on your link for NodeJS+Express. I went through hundreds of script examples. If you can look at my example and see what I am trying to say and maybe you could guide me - I would totally appreciate it. I made the simplest code to highlight my issue with nodejs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: updated my answer to suggest a solution to the readFile hiccup.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your example. It brings me back to "workaround". This is for a simple file system thing, then there is a record listing from a very large database, then is the processing and parsing and calculating things for each record (using async or not). The point I am trying to say is this: every single portion of this nodejs has to have a workaround to handle things at the same time... Regarding the PHP - I never tried to accomodate php code from some other framework to node. Instead I tried to accomodate the PHP methodology/mindset into a NodeJS one: from scratch.

Comment: like I said, the readFile didn't block the port, it simply took some time to accommodate a very large file into the memory in a single batch which caused some delay, I can easily write code in PHP that demonstrates similar slowness using threads, threads are not magic they still need to share the same RAM and CPU. I understand your point but I think that in scale node is proven to work well

Comment: Hi - thank you for getting back. I did try it in php. I could run many simultaneous calls while the same large file would be read and it did not cause the same thing node did. I am trying to give you an example of an aspect in a typical nodejs script. I could go further and say: NodeJS needs to make a webservice call to a different server and while that happens, the port is busy and other requests will wait. Tried that too. My head burns of how many different things I have tried and tested and am at the end for trying any longer :(. But thank you! I will use it for sockets for now.

Comment: 8 months later I thought about a better answer for you. we've been using cluster for years, I don't know why I haven't thought about mentioning it here. I just recently started using pm2 for clustering so it reminded me of this question.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I found out. I will answer it with an example of a blocking code:

```
for (var k = 0; k < 15000; k++){
    console.log('Something Output');
}
res.status(200).json({test:'Heavy Load'});
```

This will block because it has to do the for loop for a long time and then after it finished it will send the output.

Now if you do the same code like this it won't block:

```
function doStuff(){
    for (var k = 0; k < 15000; k++){
        console.log('Something Output');
    }   
}
doStuff();

res.status(200).json({test:'Heavy Load'});
```

Why? Because the functions are run asynchronously...! So how will I then send the resulting response to the requesting client? Currently I am doing it as follows:

1. Run the doStuff function
2. Send a unique call reference which is then received by the ajax call on the client side.
3. Put the callback function of the client side into a waiting object.
4. Listen on a socket
5. When the doStuff function is completed, it should issue a socket message with the resulting response together with the unique reference
6. When the socket on the client side gets the message with the unique reference and the resulting response, it will then match it with the waiting callback function and run it.

Done! A bit of a workaround (as mentioned before), but it's working! It does require a socket to be listening. And that is my solution to this port-blocking situation in NodeJS.

Is there some other way? I am hoping someone answers with another way, because I am still feeling like this is some workaround. Eish! ;)